# Test a single method in isolation?

Tags: java, junit

I have an application which takes user input, parses it and then continues running. I want to write some unit tests to make sure that the input code is working correctly. Now the problem is the execution flow. In my test method, I write some input to the input stream, my program then reads it and proceeds to execeute something. Now I want to test the input after it has been given but before the program continues to execute. Let me demonstrate:

```
private void getInput(){
    System.out.println("welcome, please enter a number);
    getInput();
    System.out.println("Thank you, now starting...")
    startSimulation();
}
```

Now In my testmethod, I essentialy input 10 to the stream and then I want to assert that the output stream contains "Thank you, now starting...". I want to program to stop executing here so it doesn't continue. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code it's difficult to test. You should break it down in methods.

```
public class YourClass {

    public String getInput() {
        //from standard input or whatever
    }

    public String getOutputFromInput(String input) {
        //do your logic here        
        if ("10".equals(input)) {
            return "Thank you, now starting...";
        }
        //else... or whatever
    }

    public void printOutput(String output) {
        System.out.println(output);
    } 

}
```

Now, you can test your method:

```
@Test
public void theTest() {
    String simulatedInput = "10";
    YourClass classUnderTest = new YourClass();
    assertEquals("Thank you, now starting...", classUnderTest.getOutputFromInput(simulatedInput));
}
```

Here, you are testing your login. You don't have to test that System.out.pritln; it works, I promise. You have to design your code to be loosely coupled between other components (in this case, input and output methods).

This code is not perfect at all. It's just for the example.

Comment: Ah, that is kinda what I've done, but I can't access for example my input method because it is private. Seems like a bad idea to change that just for a test? I have a general method "getInput" which then calls other smaller methods such as "getStringInput" and "getTwoNumbers" (My inputs are pretty specific). It would be ideal if I good test these methods on their own but I can't as they are private

Comment: If you need to test private methods, it's good time for extract them to a class and make them public. Always design your code to be testable. That makes a code good.